# Efficient way to iteratively store counts in R

Tags: r, data-structures

I'm having a problem with an efficient way to store the counts of a vector which is changing over time. In my problem I start with an empty vector of length n and by each iteration I add a number to this vector, but I also want to have some type of object that acts as a counter, so if the number that I add is already in the vector then it should add 1 to the object and if it's not then it should add the value as a "name" and set it to 1.

What I want is something analogous to Python, in which we can use numbers as keys and counts as values, so then I can access both separately with `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()`.

For example, if I get the values 1, 2, 1, 4 then I would like the object to update as:

```r
> value count
      1     1
> value count
      1     1
      2     1
> value count
      1     2
      2     1
> value count
      1     2
      2     1
      4     1
```

and to access efficiently both `values` and `count` separately. I thought of using something like `plyr::count` on the vector, but I don't think that it's efficient to count at every iteration, specially if n is really large.

**Edit**: In my problem it's necessary (well, maybe not) to update the counts at every iteration.

What I'm doing is simulating data from a Dirichlet Process using the Polya urn representation. For example, suppose that I have the vector (1.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 0.2), then to get a new data point one samples from a base distribution (for example a normal distribution) and adds that value with a certain probability, or adds a previous value with a probability proportional to the frequency of the value. With numbers:

- Add the sampled value with probability 1/6, or
- Add 1.1 with probability 2/6, or 0.2 with probability 2/6, or 0.3 with probability 1/6 (i.e. the probabilities are proportional to the frecuencies)

Comment: What you are describing is `table` in base R. Try `as.data.frame(table(c(1, 2, 4, 1)))`

Comment: Why exactly are you iterating? Most functions in R are vectorized so you don't need to explicitly iterate so things work much better. In general R code works very differently than Python code so trying a direct translation is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to update counts at every iteration instead of just collecting the values and tallying them up when needed (which, as @AllenCameron explains, is done by `table`)?

Comment: @AllanCameron `table()` is a good option if I want to get the frequencies at the end, but here I want to get the frequencies at every iteration, and I think that if n is extremely large then using `table()` at every iteration is not so efficient.

Comment: @Ottie yes, I'll edit the question to explain why I need to update at every iteration

Comment: @Edovt Getting and storing counts at every iteration is not efficient. `table` is the most efficient way of doing it in R.

Comment: @AllanCameron I edited the question with the reason that I need to update this counter at every iteration

Answer (score 1):

The structure you are describing is produced by `as.data.frame(table(vec))`. There is no need to update the counts as you go along, since calling this line will give you the updated counts

```r
vec <- c(1, 2, 4, 1)

as.data.frame(table(vec))
#>   vec Freq
#> 1   1    2
#> 2   2    1
#> 3   4    1
```

Suppose I now update `vec`

```
vec <- append(vec, c(1, 2, 4, 5))
```

We get the new counts the same way

```r
as.data.frame(table(vec))
#>   vec Freq
#> 1   1    3
#> 2   2    2
#> 3   4    2
#> 4   5    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `assign` and `get0` of an environment to update the counts like:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 4)

y <- new.env()
lapply(x, function(z) {
  assign(as.character(z), get0(as.character(z), y, ifnotfound = 0) + 1, y)
  setNames(stack(mget(ls(y), y))[2:1], c("value", "count"))
})
#[[1]]
#  value count
#1     1     1
#
#[[2]]
#  value count
#1     1     1
#2     2     1
#
#[[3]]
#  value count
#1     1     2
#2     2     1
#
#[[4]]
#  value count
#1     1     2
#2     2     1
#3     4     1
```